# How to specify architecture when installing apk package

Tags: arm, alpine-linux, alpine-package-keeper

I'm building Alpine Linux in a docker container on an ARM machine, and are trying to specify the package architecture that I wish to install. I cannot see how to do this even though the package and architecture are listed at the Alpine repository. https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=mosquitto&branch=v3.4&repo=main&arch=armhf&maintainer=

I have read the Alpine apk help pages at https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_package_management but cannot see how to specify an architecture. This, for example, does not work.

```
RUN apk --no-cache add mosquitto:armhf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t need to, architecture is automatically detected.